# What books does a Chinese institution use in the undergraduate maths courses?

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, china

Can anyone share the books that a Chinese maths undergraduate follows during their course? Also what are some of the problem books and exam papers that the Chinese students use to become better in mathematics? Thank you.

Comment: China is a huge country.  University professors generally have a lot of freedom in selecting texts for their courses.  Often professors do not follow a text closely, and instead write their own course notes.  As a result this question is unanswerable, so I am voting to close.

Comment: Why are you asking this question anyway? Can you give some background?

Comment: @Dominique I have seen that Chinese are extremely good in the mathematical competitions, so I assumed them that would undergo a very hard curriculum in undergraduate mathematics, that is why I wanted to know these things so that I can also become strong in mathematics.

Comment: I think that participants in math competitions are a select few who have been given special training just for that type of competition. Their performance is not necessarily indicative of the general strength of that nation's educational system, nor how they will perform in a professional capacity later on.

Comment: Though books used by Chinese universities vary, some kind of overview or some classical and widely known books should be feasible to name, or just explain the usual contents of beginning courses, or lack thereof. Even if the motivation for the question is weak, the book part of the question is interesting.

Comment: Competitions are wildly different from serious mathematics... Excellent grounding in good mathematics does not necessarily help in competitions, at all, because they are designed to test cleverness/quickness rather than scholarship and understanding. Mostly, they expect minimal coursework (or self-study) background of the competitors.